# Why are my org-table formulas behaving like this after upgrading to version 8.3?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I recently upgraded `org-mode` to version 8.3 from version 7.9.

In previous versions of org mode, the function

```
#+TBLFM: @<$<..@>$>=0
```

would place a 0 in every cell of a table. On my system, the output is

```
|   |   |   |   |   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
#+TBLFM: @<$<..@>$>=0
```

That is, the first row is skipped. What's going on?!

I even have the unexpected

```
|   |   |   |   |   |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
#+TBLFM: @1$1..@3$5=0

|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @1$1..@1$2=0
```

while

```
| 0 |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @1$1=0
```

So it appears that the first row is ignored if the region is a rectangle. Why? Is anyone else running 8.3 getting these same results?

Comment: I'd guess that this must be related to how Org wants to treat the first row of the table, which traditionally has column labels in it, but I don't know whether this is intended and may be changed or is a bug. I'm inclined to believe this is a bug. Wouldn't hurt to ask on the Org's mailing list though.

Comment: @wvxvw I'm unfamiliar with org's mailing list. Is there a link to it? Thanks!

Comment: You can subscribe to it here: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Please report it on the mailing list.